# Optimizing and abstracting in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

What's the best way to abstract and fix this code? I'm relatively new to coding and pygame, and need some help finishing this project. It's due tomorrow, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

My goal is to create a rocket game where my spaceship should dodge blocks and collect coins, and ultimately winning the game after collecting a certain amount of coins and reaching the top.

So far, I'm having trouble with 3 main things:

- I hate that I have many lines of the same code, and want to find a way to condense it.
- I have a collision problem with a loophole that I can't fix, the spaceship passes through the block instead of colliding with it whenever it passes through the top half of it
- I'm wondering what's the best way to add scoring after collecting the coins to create an if statement that will let the user win after collecting a certain amount and reaching the top

I've tried and failed to create a class to hold my characters, and don't know how to assign them different properties like speed

```
    #  goals - get the scoring done by adding 1 to the score if the spaceship collides with the block, then deleting the block and printing the new score
    #  figure out the collision problem, fix the loophole where the spaceship can pass through the block if it is above the bottom of the block
    #  figure out a way to reduce redundancy by making a class for the stars and the block
    import pygame
    import time
    import random
    pygame.init()
    screenWidth = 700
    screenHeight = 700
    wn = pygame.display.set_mode((screenWidth, screenHeight))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Maxym's First Adventure")
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    spaceshipImg = pygame.image.load('spaceship.png')
    black = (0, 0, 0)
    blue = (50, 120, 200)


    def startmenu():
        intro = True
        while intro:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()
            wn.fill(blue)
            messagedisplay("Spaceship")
            pygame.display.update()
            gameloop()


    def thing(thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh, color):
        pygame.draw.rect(wn, color, [thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh])


    def coin(coinx, coiny, coinw, coinh, color):
        pygame.draw.rect(wn, color, [coinx, coiny, coinw, coinh])


    def spaceship(x, y):
            wn.blit(spaceshipImg, (x, y))


    def messagedisplay(text):
        font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 115)
        wn.blit(font.render(text, True, (0, 0, 0)), (0, 0))
        pygame.display.update()
        time.sleep(2)
        gameloop()


    def win():
        messagedisplay("You win")


    def crash():
        messagedisplay("You crashed")
    def collect():
        score +=1

    def gameloop():
        x = screenWidth * .45
        y = screenHeight * .8
        width = 75
        height = 132
        velocity = 50

        starx = random.randrange(0, screenWidth)
        stary = 0
        starspeed = 30
        starw = 50
        starh = 50
        star2x = random.randrange(0, screenWidth)
        star2y = 0
        star2speed = 50
        star2w = 80
        star2h = 80
        star3x = random.randrange(0, screenWidth)
        star3y = 0
        star3speed = 70
        star3w = 30
        star3h = 30
        star4x = random.randrange(0, screenWidth)
        star4y = 0
        star4speed = 30
        star4w = 200
        star4h = 40
        coinx = random.randrange(0, screenWidth/2)
        coiny = random.randrange(0, screenHeight)
        coinw = 20
        coinh = 20
        coin2x = random.randrange(0, screenWidth/2)
        coin2y = random.randrange(0, screenHeight)
        coin2w = 20
        coin2h = 20
        coin3x = random.randrange(screenWidth/2, screenWidth)
        coin3y = random.randrange(0, screenHeight)
        coin3w = 20
        coin3h = 20
        coin4x = random.randrange(screenWidth/2, screenWidth)
        coin4y = random.randrange(0, screenHeight)
        coin4w = 20
        coin4h = 20
        coin5x = random.randrange(0, screenWidth)
        coin5y = random.randrange(0, screenHeight)
        coin5w = 20
        coin5h = 20
        run = True
        while run:
            pygame.time.delay(100)
            wn.fill((255, 255, 255))

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()
                print(event)

            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > velocity:
                x -= velocity
            if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < screenWidth-width-velocity:
                x += velocity
            if keys[pygame.K_UP] and y > velocity:
                    y -= velocity
            if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and y < screenHeight-height-velocity:
                    y += velocity
            pygame.draw.rect(wn, (255, 255, 255), (x, y, width, height))
            thing(starx, stary, starw, starh, black)
            thing(star2x, star2y, star2w, star2h, black)
            thing(star3x, star3y, star3w, star3h, black)
            thing(star4x, star4y, star4w, star4h, black)
            coin(coinx, coiny, coinw, coinh, blue)
            coin(coin2x, coin2y, coin2w, coin2h, blue)
            coin(coin3x, coin3y, coin3w, coin3h, blue)
            coin(coin4x, coin4y, coin4w, coin4h, blue)
            coin(coin5x, coin5y, coin5w, coin5h, blue)

            stary += starspeed
            star2y += star2speed
            star3y += star3speed
            star4y += star4speed
            if stary > screenHeight:
                stary = 0 - starh
                starx = random.randrange(0, screenWidth)
            if star2y > screenHeight:
                star2y = 0 - star2h
                star2x = random.randrange(0, screenWidth)
            if star3y > screenHeight:
                star3y = 0 - star3h
            if star4y > screenHeight:
                star4y = 0 - star4h
            score = 0
            if y + height >= stary and y + height <= stary + starh or y <= stary + starh and y + height >= stary + starh:
                if x + width >= starx and x + width <= starx + starw or x <= starx + starw and x + width >= starx + starw:
                    crash()
            if y + height >= star2y and y + height <= star2y + star2h or y <= star2y + star2h and y + height >= star2y + star2h:
                if x + width >= star2x and x + width <= star2x + star2w or x <= star2x + star2w and x + width >= star2x + star2w:
                    crash()
            if y + height >= star3y and y + height <= star3y + star3h or y <= star3y + star3h and y + height >= star3y + star3h:
                if x + width >= star3x and x + width <= star3x + star3w or x <= star3x + star3w and x + width >= star3x + star3w:
                    crash()
            if y + height >= star4y and y + height <= star4y + star4h or y <= star4y + star4h and y + height >= star4y + star4h:
                if x + width >= star4x and x + width <= star4x + star4w or x <= star4x + star4w and x + width >= star4x + star4w:
                    crash()
            if y + height >= coiny and y + height <= coiny + coinh or y <= coiny + coinh and y + height >= coiny + coinh:
                if x + width >= coinx and x + width <= coinx + coinw or x <= coinx + coinw and x + width >= coinx + coinw:
                    collect()
            if y + height >= coin2y and y + height <= coin2y + coin2h or y <= coin2y + coin2h and y + height >= coin2y + coin2h:
                if x + width >= coin2x and x + width <= coin2x + coin2w or x <= coin2x + coin2w and x + width >= coin2x + coin2w:
                    collect()
            if y + height >= coin3y and y + height <= coin3y + coin3h or y <= coin3y + coin3h and y + height >= coin3y + coin3h:
                if x + width >= coin3x and x + width <= coin3x + coin3w or x <= coin3x + coin3w and x + width >= coin3x + coin3w:
                    collect()
            if y + height >= coin4y and y + height <= coin4y + coin4h or y <= coin4y + coin4h and y + height >= coin4y + coin4h:
                if x + width >= coin4x and x + width <= coin4x + coin4w or x <= coin4x + coin4w and x + width >= coin4x + coin4w:
                    collect()
            if y + height >= coin5y and y + height <= coin5y + coin5h or y <= coin5y + coin5h and y + height >= coin5y + coin5h:
                if x + width >= coin5x and x + width <= coin5x + coin5w or x <= coin5x + coin5w and x + width >= coin5x + coin5w:
                    collect()

            if y <= 10 and score >= 3:
                win()
            spaceship(x, y)
            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(60)


    startmenu()
    gameloop()
    pygame.quit()
    quit()
```

Comment: keep values in `list` instead of variables `star`, `star2`, etc. And then you can use `for` loop to make code shorter.

Comment: instead of `thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh,` (and similar) you should use [pygame.Rect()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html)  and then you can have `def thing(thing_rect, color):` instead of ` `def thing(thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh, color):` and `pygame.draw.rect(wn, color, thing_rect)` instead of `pygame.draw.rect(wn, color, [thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh])`

Comment: `pygame.Rect` has functions to check collisions. And it has `rect.bottom` to get `rect.y + rect.height` and `rect.right` to get `rect.x + rect.width`

Answer (score 1):

Keep values in `list` instead of variables `star`, `star2`, etc. And then you can use `for` loop to make code shorter.

---

Instead of `thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh` (and similar) you should use [pygame.Rect()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) and then you can have

```
def thing(thing_rect, color):
```

instead of

```
def thing(thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh, color):
```

and

```
pygame.draw.rect(wn, color, thing_rect)
```

instead of

```
pygame.draw.rect(wn, color, [thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh])
```

---

`pygame.Rect` has functions to check collisions so you don't have to write long code in `if`.

---

`pygame.Rect` has `rect.bottom` to get `rect.y + rect.height` and `rect.right` to get `rect.x + rect.width`

Answer (score 1):

An immediate gain would be made from moving the "coin" into a simple data structure, then keep a list of them, rather than 6 quasi-static objects.

This allows you to loop over a list of coins, with only a single set of testing code.  Consider the snippet:

```
MAX_COINS = 6
all_coins = []

def addCoin( colour=(0,30,240), coinw=20, coinh=20 ):
    global all_coins
    coinx = random.randrange(0, screenWidth/2)
    coiny = random.randrange(0, screenHeight)
    all_coins.append( [ colour, pygame.Rect( coinx, coiny, coinw, coinh ) ] )

def drawCoin( window, coin ):
    coin_colour = coin[0]
    coin_rect   = coin[1]
    pygame.draw.rect( window, coin_colour, coin_rect )

...

# Create 6 coins, or add more if one/some collected
for i in range( MAX_COINS - len( all_coins ) ):
    addCoin()

# Draw all coins
for coin in all_coins:
    drawCoin( screen, coin )

# Check coin collision with player
for coin in all_coins:
    player_rect = pygame.Rect( x, y, width, height )
    coin_rect   = coin[1]
    if ( pygame.Rect.colliderect( player_rect, coin_rect ) ):
        all_coins.del( coin )  # remove the coin from the coin-list  
        collect()
```

This code presents a coin-solution which perhaps has a few less lines than the existing code, but now supports any number of coins, and protects the code from typo-bugs.  Furthermore if the collision code needs to be changed, there is only one-set of logic to analyse and fix.  A nearly identical change could be made for the `Star` objects (maybe even just store the type into the coin-like object, and use it for both).

Of course this code closely matches the workings of the already-existing [PyGame Sprite library](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html).  Refactoring to use sprites would be an even better change.